# Make routing work if the view containing the link-to tag is outside of the application view in ember.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, ember.js

i am new to ember.js and web application development and find the documentation hard to use for edge cases.

My problem is that i want to use the panel view of jquery mobile with ember js. Unfortunately the div tags of the panel are not working for me if put into a ember view tag. So i defined the leftpanel, rightpanel and the main content div tag inside the body tag.
Then i set the application root of ember.js to point to the mainContent.

To fill in the left panel i had to insert an ember view manually outside of the application root and give it some context/controllers. This works like intended and the left panel is filled with a list of 'mensas'. But now the route to display the theken-view template does not work if activated from the leftpanel. If i test it with a dummy link from inside the application view the route works.

**Error Message**

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/mensa/1 404 (File not found) jq.js:7845
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jq.js:7845
...
$.mobile.changePage jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:5577
jQuery.event.dispatch jq.js:4676
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle jq.js:4360
```

**Javascript**

```
window.Mensa = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: $('#application')
});

Mensa.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        host: "http://127.0.0.1:8002/api",
    })
});

Mensa.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});

Mensa.Mensa = DS.Model.extend({
    name:DS.attr('string'),  
    theken: DS.hasMany('theke',{ async: true })
});

Mensa.Theke = DS.Model.extend({
    name:DS.attr('string'),
    mensa: DS.belongsTo('mensa',{ async: true })
});


Mensa.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('mensa',{path:"mensa/:mensa_id"})
});

Mensa.MensaView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:'theken-view', 
});

Mensa.MensaRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(params){
    return this.store.getById('mensa',params.mensa_id).get('theken')
  }
})

Mensa.MensasListView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:'mensa-view', 
});

Mensa.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('mensa');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
      this._super(controller, model);
      this.setupMensa();
  },
  setupMensa: function(){
    var view = Mensa.MensasListView.create({context:this.controller,controller:this.controller});
    view.replaceIn('#mensaList');
  }
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<body>
  <div data-role="panel" id="leftpanel"  data-position="left">
      <div class="ui-panel-inner" id="mensaList">   
     </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="header">
      <h1 id="mensaTitle">Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="application" class="mainContent">
  </div>
  <div data-role="panel" id="rightpanel" data-position="right">
      <div class="ui-panel-inner" >
      </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
  <!-- This link works as intended -->
  {{#link-to 'mensa' '1'}}Link{{/link-to}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="mensas" data-template-name="mensa-view">
  <ul data-role="listview"  class="ui-listview">
  {{#each model contentBinding="this"}}
      <li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child">

      <!-- This link does not work -->
      {{#link-to 'mensa' id class="ui-link-inherit"}}
        {{ name}}
      {{/link-to}}</li>
      {{else}} nooooo
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="thekes" data-template-name="theken-view">
  <ul data-role="listview"  class="ui-listview">
  {{#each model contentBinding="this"}}
      <li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child">{{ name}}</li>
      {{else}} nooooo
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use something to hijack the links since you are using `location: 'history'`.

The reason it works for Ember is they are hijacking the click on the links and replacing history state.

You can use `history.pushState` to replace the page without reloading it.

Comment: But mensa-view is an ember view so it should use the ember routing. If i remove location "history" it does not work either.

Comment: manually calling history.pushState(null, null, 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/mensa/1'); is not working too